# Move elements to list when window to small to show them

Tags: javascript

I am working on a toolbar for my website and currently I have populated it with random buttons, and I want them to move to another list if the window is resized and the buttons cannot fit.

Here is the code:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById("button_holder");
    var divRight = document.getElementById('button_holder_right');
    var extraButton = document.getElementById('barMoreButton');
    var extraMenu = document.getElementById('extraMenu');
    var i;
    widthOfResizeMenuItems = 0;
    for (i=0;i<div.childNodes.length;i++) {
        var button = div.childNodes[i];
        if( widthOfResizeMenuItems > div.offsetWidth ) {
            button.remove();
            extraMenu.appendChild(button);
            extraButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
            divRight.width = 78;
        }else if( widthOfResizeMenuItems < div.offsetWidth ) {
            if( extraMenu.childNodes.length > 0 ) {
                div.appendChild(extraMenu.childNodes[0]);
            }
            extraButton.style.display = 'none';
            divRight.width = 52;
        }
        widthOfResizeMenuItems = widthOfResizeMenuItems + button.offsetWidth;
    }
    console.log("Count: " + i + " --- Width: " + widthOfResizeMenuItems);
}
```

heres the bars structure

```
div#srgapi_toolbar
    table
        tr
            td#button_holder
                button (x9)
            td#button_holder_right
                button#barMoreButton
div#extraMenu
```

and here is a demo: http://api.shadowravengames.co.uk/test.php
try resizing the window to see what is happening at the moment

What am I doing wrong, why are the elements wrapping to a new line instead of moving to the other menu, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You should take a look at some jQuery responsive menus

Comment: I can't use jQuery, I have a chrome extension that loads it in, and if a page already has jQuery or Prototype, is breaks things, so I am building it entirely out of Javascript

Comment: "entirely out of Javascript". You mean entirely out of jQuery right?

Comment: Could you log the div.offsetWidth? Or event better provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: "Javascript" not "jQuery", 
I do log the div.offsetWidth, check the console.., 
Here is a jsFiddle I set up http://jsfiddle.net/MRVDOG/LyJnR/3/

Comment: Rusty english. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it. There are two problems.

1. You have to consider the size 26 of your extra barMoreButton. That will fix the problem of button 9 not moving to the blue menu.
2. By using remove() you break the loop.

> ```
> if( widthOfResizeMenuItems + 26 >= div.offsetWidth ) {
>   button.remove();
>   i = i-1;
>   ...
> }
> ```

By reducing the i variable you don't break the loop of your child elements.

//Now that I look at it again, the order gets messed up when I reach button 4 or something.
Let me look at it a little more and come back with a solution.

Comment: Haven't had the time to check the problem of order messing up. The answer is not complete. The "+26" is a hack, you should take into consideration the divRight.width. But if you do, you will have to change some things about the flow of your code. If I find the time I will update my answer but glad to be of some help.

Comment: Well I still haven't got it working properly, have you had any luck?

Comment: Ohhh yea, got it working :D, I'm so happy, I can continue with the project now :), thanks for your help @Alkis, here is the code if you wan't to check it out http://jsfiddle.net/MRVDOG/LyJnR/7/